# Translation as a Master’s lthesis

Tags: academic-writing, translation, paper

Hi I am on final semester of my Master’s programme in Islamic Finance and my supervisor suggested me to translate one of his book from Arabic to English as my thesis. I wonder does translation counts as a thesis and is it ethical?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I think this question is better suited to Academia.SE, since you're coming at it from an academic point of view. I'm certain, however, that what you're describing is plagiarism, which is *bad*.

Answer (score 3):

Is it original research? No. Is it expanding your thinking? No. Is it a pathway to a PhD? No. Is it ethical? No. Do you see a theme emerging? There is no way that translating a book into English is a thesis. Even if you were doing a degree in foreign languages, it wouldn't qualify because it isn't your original research.

Sack your supervisor. Find a topic you are interested in and that will help you in the future.